# Display moveable view with input

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I want to make a view that hold many object like this picture.
Each of that holds text. And can be connected with drag gesture. (Just like Storyboard in Xcode)

[image: Imgur]

How can I make that? What do I need?

Answer (score 1):

I would make a custom UIView subclass with a CATextLayer for each text area, and a CAShapeLayer for each line.

Then I'd respond to user touch inputs on the view and move the layers around as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I think that's the way. This is crazy. 
Is there anyone who ever made this before? It's really easy to accomplish this with HTML. But it requires internet connection, and will be a laggy app as it's not a native application.
Do you have any app reference? I wonder if someone has ever made this.

Comment: @EdwardAnthony I don't think HTML would be any easier than core animation. If anything it would be harder with HTML. You're overestimating how much work is involved. I'm not sure if anyone has posted code demonstrating how to do it.